# PHP достать 2 букву со строки

Tags: php

Есть строка "abc".

Как на php посредством substr мне достать вторую букву?

Пишу: `substr('abc', 0, 2)`, но не помогает.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 10):

Вторая буква - это буква номер 1, т.к. считают с нуля. Если надо одну букву. то и длина = 1.

```
substr('abc', 1, 1)
```

Но если строка - это переменная, а не литерал, то можно и по индексу:

```
$a = 'abc';
$second_letter = $a[1];
```

Comment: Только не нужно забывать, ЭТО - не работает с `uttf-8` и нужно использовать `mb_*` функции.